# Отступы ViewPager android

Tags: android-viewpager, android

Как можно реализовать отступы по кругу так, чтобы при скроллинге страниц сами страницы, как бы могли по этому отступу так же скроллиться. В общем, при использовании конструкции на viewpager

```
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
```

такого эффекта не получается достичь, потому что отступ бывает, но при скроллинге он "поглощает" страницу

UPD. Решение:

```
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
```

Comment: эээ вас не туда занесло, вам нужна анимация появления\удаления при скролинге

Comment: Нет, не нужна. Решил вопрос через конструкции типа:     android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:clipToPadding="false"

Comment: `ViewPager.setPageMargin()`?

Comment: Это между страницами, а мне нужно было со всех сторон отступы. Сейчас скину в первый пост как получилось решить проблему.

Comment: @makavelka, пожалуйста, оформите решение в качестве ответа, чтобы Вы могли получить заслуженную репутацию. Если Вы не успеете сделать это до 09.08, я оформлю ответ в качестве общего (за него не начисляется репутация) - это необходимо для улучшения структуризации содержимого сайта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:

```
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
```